# How can I modify powerpoint presentation that has 10 slides into new order?

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I have powerpoint presentation that has 10 slides that has shapes, text and audio. I need to modify it to make the ten slides into 50 slides with the same contents but in diffrent order as shown in this code but I get error.

I tried to run the code but always there is an error I can not see what is my mistake

and this is a code:

```
import pptx
from pptx.util import Inches

# Open an existing PowerPoint presentation

presentation = pptx.Presentation('C:/Users/ZBOOK/Desktop/ppt/existing_presentation.pptx')

# Store the slides in a list

slides = \[\]
for slide in presentation.slides:
slides.append(slide)

# Modify the order of the slides as described

start = 1
for i in range(1, 11):
for j in range(5):
slide_index = (start + j - 1) % 10
slide = slides\[slide_index\]
slide.shapes.title.text = "slide\\t" + str(slide_index + 1)
print("slide\\t" + str(slide_index + 1))
start += 1

# Remove all the slides from the presentation

for i in range(len(presentation.slides), 0, -1):
presentation.slides.remove_slide(i - 1)

# Add the modified slides back to the presentation

for slide in slides:
presentation.slides.add_slide(slide)

# Save the modified presentation

presentation.save('C:/Users/ZBOOK/Desktop/ppt/modified_presentation.pptx')
```

Comment: What is the exact text of the error message and on what line does it occur?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ZBOOK\Desktop\ppt\ppt2.py", line 18, in <module>
    slide.shapes.title.text = "slide\t" + str(slide_index + 1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'